# Focus listener for android TextView?

Tags: android, textview, setfocus

I created a layout with `TextView` and `EditText` and setted the `FocusListener` for both view.
but I am not able to get the focus for `TextView`. I try a hardcoded `requestFocus` as well, but it's also not working.

Any one have any idea about it?

Comment: had u given setFocusable true for text field ?

Comment: i don't think textview is focusable by default

Comment: @Sandy09 I am using it..but still I am getting no action when I try to move focus on textView..I am using fragmentation..is it something because of this?..any idea.